# How to animate color change swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to animate the color transition between green, yellow, and red. How would I go about this? I have tried using `animation()` on the Circle view, but this created weird bugs in which the `StrokeStyle` seems to be ignored and the whole circle fills with color during the transition.

[image: Timer countdown gif]

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

struct CircleTimer_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            CircleTimer()        }
    }
}

struct CircleTimer : View {
    @State var to: CGFloat = 1;
    @State var start = false
    @State var count = 15
    let defaultTime = 15
    @State var time = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View{
        
        ZStack{
            
            Color.black.opacity(0.06).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            
            VStack{
                
                ZStack{
                    
                    Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: 1)
                        .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.09), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 35, lineCap: .round))
                    .frame(width: 280, height: 280)
                    
                    Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: self.to)
                    .stroke(self.count > 10 ? Color.green : self.count > 5 ? Color.yellow : Color.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 35, lineCap: .round))
 
                    .frame(width: 280, height: 280)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(180), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
                    
                    VStack{
                        
                        Text("\(self.count)")
                            .font(.system(size: 72))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                }
                TimerButtons(start: $start, to: $to, count: $count)
            }
            
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge,.sound,.alert]) { (_, _) in
            }
        })
        .onReceive(self.time) { (_) in
            
            if self.start{
                
                if self.count > 0 {
                    
                        self.count -= 1
                    
                    print(self.count)
                    
                    withAnimation(.default){
                        
                        self.to = CGFloat(self.count) / 15
                        print(self.to)
                    }
                }
                else{
                    self.start.toggle()
                }

            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't a bug. It is doing what you told it to do. Remember, the struct redraws EVERYTHING for an update. If you want to have different colors on the ring, you will need to use 3 different circles, each with a different color that are trimmed as you want, OR you could use a gradient.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64685825/12299030?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Yrb, you must create three separate views of three different colors.